# Использование pipe в Python "Bad file descriptor"

Tags: python, linux, многопоточность, ос

Пытаюсь написать калькулятор, в котором все вычисления производятся в дочернем процессе, после чего он возвращает результат родительскому. Программа отрабатывает корректно один раз, а дальше-выдает ошибку "Bad file descriptor"

В чем может быть причина? Все ломается как только добавляю цикл.

```
import os
class Calculator:

    operations = ['+', '-', '*', '/', '.']
    def add(self, a, b):
        return a + b

    def subtract(self, a, b):
        return a - b

    def multiply(self, a, b):
        return a * b

    def divide(self, a, b):
        return a / b

    def get_expression(self):
        user_input = input("Input the expression: op n1 n2 ")
        return bytes(user_input, encoding="UTF-8")

    def check_expression(self, expression):
        if len(expression) != 3 :
            return 0
        if (expression[0] not in self.operations):
            return 0
        else:
            return 1

    def check_quit(self, user_input):
        user_input = user_input.decode("utf-8").split()
        if user_input[0] == '.':
            return 1
        else:
            return 0

    def find_result(self, user_input):
        user_input = user_input.decode("utf-8").split()
        operand = user_input[0]
        a = int(user_input[1])
        b = int(user_input[2])
        if operand == '+':
            return str(my_cl.add(a, b)).encode("utf-8")
        elif (operand == '-'):
            return str(my_cl.subtract(a, b)).encode("utf-8")
        elif (operand == '*'):
            return str(my_cl.multiply(a, b)).encode("utf-8")
        elif (operand == '/'):
            return str(my_cl.divide(a, b)).encode("utf-8")
        else:
            print("ERROR")

my_cl = Calculator()

r2, w2 = os.pipe()
r1, w1 = os.pipe()

pid = os.fork()

while(1):
    if pid > 0:
        os.close(r2)
        os.close(w1)
        user_input = my_cl.get_expression()
        os.write(w2, user_input)
        print("Result:", os.read(r1, 100).decode("utf-8"))

    else:
        os.close(w2)
        os.close(r1)
        user_input = os.read(r2, 100)
        os.write(w1, my_cl.find_result(user_input))
```

Comment: Вытащите все close из цикла

Comment: Я пробовал разные варианты расстановки close-ов и все они выдают похожую ошибку:
``` lang-cpp  
pid = os.fork()  </br>
os.close(r2)  </br>
os.close(w1)  </br>
os.close(w2)  
os.close(r1)  
while(1):  
   ....  
'```   
_**Input the expression: op n1 n2 Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "/home/slav/PycharmProjects/pp_hw1/main.py", line 72, in <module>  
    user_input = os.read(r2, 100)  
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor **_

Comment: А без цикла read/write отрабатывают нормально и вы получаете результат?

Comment: Да, без цикла все отрабатывает

Answer (score 0):

Получилось! Правда выходит избыточный if и так и не понятно почему так получалось, но это работает.

```
import os

class Calculator:

    operations = ['+', '-', '*', '/', '.']

    def add(self, a, b):
        return a + b

    def subtract(self, a, b):
        return a - b

    def multiply(self, a, b):
        return a * b

    def divide(self, a, b):
        return a / b

    def get_expression(self):
        user_input = input("Input the expression: op n1 n2 ")
        return bytes(user_input, encoding="UTF-8")

    def check_expression(self, expression):
        if len(expression) != 3:
            return 0
        if (expression[0] not in self.operations):
            return 0
        else:
            return 1

    def check_quit(self, user_input):
        user_input = user_input.decode("utf-8").split()
        if user_input[0] == '.':
            return 1
        else:
            return 0

    def find_result(self, user_input):
        user_input = user_input.decode("utf-8").split()
        operand = user_input[0]
        a = int(user_input[1])
        b = int(user_input[2])
        if operand == '+':
            return str(my_cl.add(a, b)).encode("utf-8")
        elif (operand == '-'):
            return str(my_cl.subtract(a, b)).encode("utf-8")
        elif (operand == '*'):
            return str(my_cl.multiply(a, b)).encode("utf-8")
        elif (operand == '/'):
            return str(my_cl.divide(a, b)).encode("utf-8")
        else:
            print("ERROR")


my_cl = Calculator()

r2, w2 = os.pipe()
r1, w1 = os.pipe()

pid = os.fork()

if pid > 0:
    os.close(r2)
    os.close(w1)
else:
    os.close(w2)
    os.close(r1)
while (1):
    if pid > 0:
        user_input = my_cl.get_expression()
        os.write(w2, user_input)
        print("Result:", os.read(r1, 100).decode("utf-8"))

    else:
        user_input = os.read(r2, 100)
        os.write(w1, my_cl.find_result(user_input))
```

Comment: Изучайте матчасть (OS, наверное лучше *nix) глубже. Файловый дескриптор ([pipe](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) создает именно их) можно закрывать **только один раз**. Поэтому в цикле и не работает